# tensorflow reduce_mean vs numpy mean

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, mean

As far as I understand tensorflow reduce_mean and numpy mean should return identical values, but below example returns different values:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

t_1 = tf.constant([1,3,4,5])
t_2 = tf.constant([7,8,9,0])
list_t = [t_1, t_2]
reduced_t_list = tf.reduce_mean(list_t)
sess= tf.Session()
print(sess.run(reduced_t_list))
print(np.mean([1,3,4,5,7,8,9,0]))

output:
4
4.625
```

Any guesses why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`tf.constant` docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/constant_op/constant_value_tensors#constant):

```
If the argument dtype is not specified, then the type is inferred from the type of value.
```

The `dtype` of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is `int`, whereas `np.mean([1, 2, 3])` casts it to an array of `float`s by default.

Try `tf.constant(np.arange(3.0))`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am failing to grasp why data type matters. Do you think tensorflow rounds 4.625 to 4?

Comment: yep, integer division (and taking an average of multiple integers is first summing integers and then diving over total number of these integers) usually does [floor division](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) by default, e.g. `27 // 10 == 2` even though `2.7` seems to be closer to `3`.